# Correct way to do cross validation in a pipeline with imbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, imbalanced-data, smote

For the given imbalanced data , I have created a different pipelines for standardization & one hot encoding

```python
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler())])
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=['ohe', OneHotCategoricalEncoder()])
```

After that a column transformer keeping the above pipelines in one

```python
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer,categorical_features)]
```

The final pipeline is as below

```python
smt = SMOTE(random_state=42)
rf = pl1([('preprocessor', preprocessor),('smote',smt),
                      ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])
```

I am doing the pipeline fit on imbalanced data so i have included the SMOTE technique along with the pre-processing and classifier. As it is imbalanced I want to check for the recall score.

Is the correct way as shown in the code below? I am getting recall around 0.98 which can cause the model to overfit. Any suggestions if I am making any mistake?

```python
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=5,scoring="recall")
```

Comment: You are applying the pipeline correctly for your CV procedure. The statement "*I am getting recall around 0.98 which can cause the model to overfit*" is completely incomprehensible.

Comment: Thank you, I had a doubt if the process of selecting the cross_validation is wrong in the pipeline. Also this is my first implementation on pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important concern in imbalanced settings is to ensure that enough members of the minority class will be present in each CV fold; thus, it would seem advisable to enforce that using `StratifiedKFold`, i.e.:

```python
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)  
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=skf, scoring="recall")
```

Nevertheless, it turns out that even when using the `cross_val_score` as you do (i.e. simply with `cv=5`), scikit-learn takes care of it and engages a stratified CV indeed; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html):

> **cv : *int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None***
>
> - None, to use the default 5-fold cross validation,
> - int, to specify the number of folds in a `(Stratified)KFold`.
>
> For int/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and `y` is either
>   binary or multiclass, `StratifiedKFold` is used. In all other cases,
>   `KFold` is used.

So, using your code as is:

```python
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=5, scoring="recall")
```

is absolutely fine indeed.

Comment: Isn't the default cross-validation strategy for `cross_val_score` StratifiedKFold anyway (provided the problem is single-output)?

Comment: @BenReiniger heck, you are right! I missed that :( Would you like to post this as an answer yourself (and I'll ask from the OP to accept yours)? Otherwise I will update mine - your call...